# how to get value from database with javascript, i am using jquery autocomplete, and i want to search values from database only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm using jquery autocomplete

```
<script>
$(function() {    
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Scheme"
      ];    
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags  });});
</script>
```

and how can i take an array value from database to var availableTags... 
thanks bro :D

Comment: solved. i replace var availableTags with this

var availableTags = [
    <?php 
      foreach ($nama_barang as $row_nama) {
        echo "'".$row_nama->nm_barang."',";
      }
     ?>
    ];

Comment: and how it will be seriously affect with the security ?? could you tell me ?

Comment: Client side database operations are not a good practice , hackers can easily hack your site using these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to access database and get list of values in your autocomplete you need to use a server side programming language as in this example we use php.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minLength: 2,//search after two characters
select: function(event,ui){
    //do something
    }
});
```

after search.php will be called asynchronously source will have this data extracted from the database.

```
source: [{"value":"Some Name","id":1},{"value":"Some Othername","id":2}]
```

I give you an example how php code should be

```
//connect to your database

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT description as value,id FROM test WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

have good luck for more info http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/